# Testing Airflow DAG for errors prior to trigger

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, airflow

Is there a quick/simple way to check an Airflow (**1.10**) DAG script for errors such as syntax errors, task errors etc from the command line (or any other way) prior to triggering the DAG ?

In our project we have to first push the DAG code to Stash and then deploy it thru Jenkins before we can actually run the DAG. Hence we can find out errors only after triggering it.

This becomes very tedious when we have to repeatedly go thru the same process to discover and fix every minor coding errors.

So checking if there is a quick way to check and fix for these errors before we trigger the DAG.

Airflow Version - **1.10**

Thanks